# is there any jmeter plugin available to display the stats during the execution of cloud based remote host?

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I am trying to find a jemter plugin which is help to display the remote host stats (Cloud based) during the execution. Does someone can help me on this with your expertise

I have search on many blogs and research papaers

Comment: Jmeter is a tool for testing, not for monitoring. It is not recommended to run jmeter in gui mode in case of more or less serious load test. In general Jmeter GUI is supposed to be used only to set up test parameters in a convenient manner, so I would not expect to find such plugin. The most of clouds provide you cloud monitoring tools, why won't you use them instead?

Comment: Yes I Agree with you,I may not clear with the question I raised. There are lot of plugings which we can used for our jmeter execution such as KPI vs KPI Graphs to monitor the performance stats. I am checking whether we have a puging to use in jmeter to monitor application behavior .... i was thinking that can there be any pluging instead of direct cloud monitoring

Comment: I think if such a plugin exists it would be cloud specific, which cloud do you use?

Comment: I am trying to use with AWS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my understanding of your query, you want to monitor jmeter test (response time,error rate,TPS etc ) from some portal (preferably cloud) during execution. I haven't seen such plugin for cloud. But you can use Jmeter+Grafana+influxDB integration. Integration needs some efforts to set up but it's one-time effort and setup can be reused. Jmeter Backend listener is required to work this integration. Reference : https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-use-grafana-to-monitor-jmeter-non-gui-results

Addition to that you can monitor server-side machine level parameter by doing telegraph integration with grafana.

I hope this will help you :)